# Debug software for android devices?

Tags: android

I cannot debug my sony Ericsson xperia x10 using eclipse as it doesnot recognizes device drivers. I downloaded some drivers but device is not recognized by the OS. my OS is windows XP with service pack 3. Are there any android debug apps which can be installed in to the device and debug other apps??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sony Ericsson X10 Drivers download page is:

- http://developer.sonymobile.com/wportal/devworld/downloads/download/dw-x10drivers

A thread on xda-developers.com indicates that those ADB drivers might not work out-of-the-box with the Xperia X10 - you may have to 'patch' the .inf file.  From http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=25346573&postcount=6:

> my XPeria X10 mini (MiniCM and nAa kernel) was not recognized.
>
> I've had to add following row to sa0101usb.inf
>
> ```
> %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0FCE&PID_612E&MI_01
> ```

You may need to do something similar.

Comment: Thank you very much! .. finally problem solved.. ^_^ It s working now. :)

Answer (score 1):

The adb daemon and the processes it creates run as a somewhat more privileged userid than any of the applications you can install.  This allows things such as installing or removing packages without user confirmation, running things as the userid of debuggable application packages, etc.

For many purposes though, there are workarounds:

- You can install applications by emailing them to yourself or serving them (with appropriate mime type) from a private webserver or pushing them to the external storage via a fileserver running on the device and then opening them manually or with an Intent.  Any of these methods will require interactive user confirmation.
- Through ICS you can read the logcat log from an application if it holds a relevant manifest permission - you could for example setup an ssh server with that permission and connect into the device to read the log.  Apparently this will no longer work to the same degree in Jellybean
- If you can root the device somehow (ie with an app rather than via adb) you can setup permanent adb over tcp (ie wifi) - the way to do it without root requires first having the usb connection working, then changing modes and unplugging.

You probably will not be able to do interactive debugging, so you will need to use log messages and the like to track internal state; most of the time this is sufficient.

---

However, it's probably too soon to give up on getting the USB adb connection working.  One obvious answer would be to setup a linux partition, vm, or spare machine.  Or keep looking for the windows driver; it's probably out there, and there is likely knowledge of it on forums somewhere.

Additionally, since you are running XP you may not yet be tangling with a need for signed drivers, so it might be possible to hex-edit the VID of your phone into the driver (or its config file?) for the original android developer phones.